# Filter table in Angular based on Dropdown

Tags: angular, filter, dropdown

I'm trying to filter table based on the data passed from my dropdown.

I use reactiveForm for my Dropdown :

```
<form novalidate [formGroup]="policeform">
  <p-dropdown [options]="Assureurs" optionLabel="nom"  formControlName="assureur"></p-dropdown>
  <p-dropdown [options]="Intermediares" optionLabel="nom"  formControlName="intermediare"></p-dropdown>
```

I call 'Assureurs' and 'Interemediares' lists from Backend :

```
 getAssureurs(){
      this.policeService.getAssureursList().subscribe(
        data => {
        this.Assureurs=data;
        },
       error =>
        console.log(error));
    }
    getIntermediares(){
      this.policeService.getIntermediaresList().subscribe(
        data => {
        this.Intermediares=data;
        },
       error =>
        console.log(error));
    }

    initPoliceForm(){
      this.policeform = this.fb.group({
        assureur:[''],
        intermediare:['']
    });
    }
```

My 'Assureur' is like : (for example)

```
{
        "id":3,
        "nom": "Atla",
        "dateCreation":"2020-05-14T00:20:15.956+0000",
        "Actif":true
    }
```

This is my Filter:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'tableFilter'
})
export class TableFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(list: any[], formControls: Object) {
    const keys       = Object.keys(formControls).filter(key => formControls[key]);
    const filterUser = user => keys.every(key => {
      user[key].nom==formControls[key].nom;
     });
    return keys.length ? list.filter(filterUser) : list;
  }
}
```

But it didn't  work, it's not returning the filterd data !

This is how i use the filter :

```
<tr  *ngFor="let police of polices |async| orderBy: 'id' | tableFilter: policeform.value ">
```

Comment: The form values don't have a `nom` property.

Comment: the nom property is in the list of 'Assureur' and 'Intermediare'

Comment: But is it in `policeform.value.assureur`?

Comment: yes @AluanHaddad

Answer (score 0):

You can add in your `component.ts` file:

```
filteredPolices : Police[] = [];
_listFilter = '';
get listFilter(): string {
      return this._listFilter;
}

set listFilter(value: string){
      this._listFilter = value;
      this.filteredPolices = this.listFilter ? this.performFilter(this.listFilter) : this.polices;
}
```

Implement the performFilter method:

```
performFilter(filterBy: string): Police[]{
      // implement you filter and return the result
}
```

In your HTML file add `[(ngModel)]="listFilter"` to the dropdown

and loop through you filtered data:

```
<tr *ngFor="let police of filteredPolices | orderBy: 'id' ">
```

Hope this help.